# Animate UIKit Item with Scene Transition

Tags: iphone, uikit, cocos2d-iphone

I have added a couple of UIKit items to my layer, a UITableView, and a UITextField.

How do I get those items to animate with the rest of the scene during a transition?

I have tried both adding the items via the CCDirector,

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:tableView];
```

As well as using the CCUIViewWrapper class.

Either way, the cocos2d items all transition, but the UIKit items remain on screen and will not animate with the rest of the screen.

```
HelloWorldLayer *scene = (HelloWorldLayer *)[HelloWorldLayer scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionZoomFlipX transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:(CCScene *)scene]];
```

Just for testing, I used the rotating button example shown here:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889
and added the replaceScene code above to the button action.

if you also add a CCLabelTTF to the screen, you will notice the label animates with the transition, but the Button does not.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with a UIWebView, i had to use UIView animations to move them

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        //Animation

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            //Completed
        }
    }];
```

Although, ***BE WARNED*** the UIView animate Block animates at a different speed compared to the:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionZoomFlipX transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene:(CCScene *)scene]];
```

I have yet to find a perfect solution, but i found as i was animating the UIView if I faded it out as i was animating it, it made it look a lot smoother

Answer (score 0):

There are four different types of `directors` in Cocos2D. Some support UIKit while others do not. It is possible your issue will be resolved by instantiating a different director object.